# Size-biased picking, random exchangeable partitions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\Pi$ be a random exchangeable (its law is invariant under action of any permutation with finite support) partition of $\mathbb{N}$. We define mass of a block of partition of $\mathbb{N}$ as $\left| B \right| = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\left| B \cap \{1,2,\ldots , n \} \right|}{n}$.
Lets assume that there are only finite numbers of blocks.
We define $X$ to be mass of the block containing 1 and $Y$ to be mass of randomly choosen block of the random exchangeable partition. We are to prove that

$\mathbb{P} \left( X \in dx \right)=\frac{x}{\mathbb{E} Y} \mathbb{P} \left( Y \in dx \right)$

Comment: It comes from book "Recent Progress in Coalescent Theory" of Berestycki, p.12.

Comment: What is dx in these equations?

Comment: @BrianRushton I would assume derivative.